# MySQL problem: autoID not starting with 1

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I'm creating a new table from scratch through scripting - first, I'm dropping it (in case it already exists):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `myTable`
```

then I'm creating it:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myTable` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
... and so on
```

The problem: for some strange reason, my `autoID-field ALWAYS starts at 2028 instead of 1`, although I'm generating it from scratch. What is wrong?

Comment: Not sure about the answer but you don't need to check if the table exists if your dropping it prior to the command. It will always be true. Instead wrap the drop table part if an if as your can't drop the drop if it doesn't exist and trying to was raise an error.

Comment: Does it really matter what value the ID starts at anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the end of create block. You probably have something like `AUTO_INCREMENT=2028`. If this is the case just put `AUTO_INCREMENT=1` at the end of create table block

such as

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myTable` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
...
) ENGINE=xxx AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myTable` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

Please add primary key

Answer (score 0):

You can update it by altering the table

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```